# Why won't my CSS and HTML render properly in IE and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am currently creating a landing page and I can't seem to figure out what is the problem in my code. Specially on the positioning of a particular div. It displays properly in IE but when I open it to chrome it is not positioned properly. Is there a way I can make it look the same in each browser? Because when I edit the positioning in the Chrome browser it doesn't even move a bit. Base on the code below the div that is in the wrong position is the id="selfService".

PS: I tried to edit the css file and it seems that the bottom: 90%; in the #selfService is not working on the chrome browser and it is working on the IE browser. why does chrome browser not applying the bottom: 90%; code?

```css
#container5 {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 25em;
border-bottom: 3em solid #0175c9;
}

#bigcontainer {
height: 48em;
}

#maincontainer {
width: 36%;
height: 44em;
background-color: deepskyblue;
margin-left: 1.5%;
}

#upcomingActivitiesTitle {
text-align: center;
color: white;
font-size: 25pt;
font-family: arial;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px 

white;
position: relative;
top: 10%;
}

#container {
width: 90%;
height: 25em;
margin-left: 5%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top: 15%;
}

#subcontainer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 25em;
margin: auto;
}

#patching {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #234090;
padding: 0.1em;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 22pt;
}

#patchingDesc {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
}

#networkMaintenance {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #234090;
padding: 0.1em;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 22pt;
}

#networkMaintenanceDesc {
width: 80%;
margin: auto;
color: white;
font-family: arial;
}

#container #subcontainer {
  animation: slide 13s 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-top: 0;}
  10% {margin-top: -10em;}
  20% {margin-top: -17em;}
  30% {opacity: 1;}
  40% {margin-top: -30em;}
  41% {opacity: 0;}
  61% {opacity: 0;}
  62% {opacity: 1;}
  63% {margin-top: 24em;}
  80% {margin-top: 17em;}
  90% {margin-top: 10em;}
  100% {margin-top: 0;}

}



#clickMore {
position: relative;
display: inline;
background-color: #0098cc;
border-radius: 7px;
font-family: arial;
color: white;
font-size: 14pt;
padding: 0.1em;
float: right;
right: 15%;
top: 15%;
}

#clickMore > a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
}

#tutorialVideos {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 10em;
width: 55%;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 44em;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 41%;
line-height: 10em;
background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/VideoBanner.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position:center;
}

#calendar {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 10em;
width: 55%;
border-radius: 5px;
bottom: 43em;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 41%;
line-height: 10em;
background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/CentralizedCalendar.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position:center;
}

a > #calendar {
text-decoration: none;
color: deepskyblue;
}

#selfService {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
height: 21em;
width: 55%;
bottom: 90%;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
margin-right: 3%;
float: right;
}

#titleSelfService {
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 22pt;
}

#howto {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 25%;
font-size: 15pt;
margin-left: 19%;
}

#hpsm {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 25%;
font-size: 15pt;
margin-left: 11%;
}

#imghowto {
width: 100%;
height: 10em;
background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/HowTo.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}

#imghpsm {
width: 100%;
height: 10em;
background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/HPSM.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
}

#hpsm > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

#howto > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigcontainer">
   <div id="maincontainer">
      <div id="upcomingActivitiesTitle">Upcoming Activities</div>
      <div id="container">
         <div id="subcontainer">
            <br/>
            <br/> 
            <div id="patching">Unix Patching 2.0</div>
            <div id="patchingDesc"> 
               <b>The Unix Team will have a 5- hour regular maintenance on Sunday, 23 

April 2017 starting 08:00 AM ET. There will be no user disruption during this 

activity</b></div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/> 
            <div id="networkMaintenance">Network Maintenance</div>
            <div id="networkMaintenanceDesc"> 
               <b>The Unix Team will have a 5-hour regular maintenance on Sunday, 23 

April 2017 starting 08:00AM ET. There will be no user disruption during this 

activity.</b></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="clickMore">
         <a href="#">Click More</a></div>
   </div> 
   <a id="tutorialsa" href="#">
      <div id="tutorialVideos">&#160;</div></a><a id="calendara" href="#">
      <div id="calendar">&#160;</div></a>
   <div id="selfService"> 
      <br/> 
      <br/>
      <div id="titleSelfService">Self Service</div> 
      <br/>
      <div id="howto">
         <a id="howtoa" href="#">How To 
            <div id="imghowto">&#160;</div></a> </div>
      <div id="hpsm">
         <a id="hpsma" href="#">HPSM 
            <div id="imghpsm">&#160;</div></a> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. The worst browser on the planet, it is incomplete and non-standards compliant. Always, ALWAYS use ANY other browser to first verify your markup looks as you wish. Then and only then look to see how IE royally screws everything up and try to fix IE. Not the other way around!

Comment: Not to sound as rant, but couldn't agree more with Rob.

Comment: Looks like the float plus `inline-block` display on the `#selfService` element is causing Chrome to ignore the positioning. Removing them both seems to at least get the `bottom` style respected -- although then you'd need to figure out a different way to achieve the right-side alignment.

Comment: My bad Rob, I think that's something I overlooked. I only did it in IE because majority of the people here in our company uses IE as their primary browser. Thanks Syden and Nate for your answers i got my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*An example of how exactly you would like `#selfService` to show would be ideal.*

You are using percentage on that `bottom` and em units on the rest, it's parent has it's `height` set on em too.

- Try tweaking `#selfService` `bottom` with em units as well.

```css
#container5 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 25em;
  border-bottom: 3em solid #0175c9;
}

#bigcontainer {
  height: 48em;
}

#maincontainer {
  width: 36%;
  height: 44em;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
}

#upcomingActivitiesTitle {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
}

#container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 25em;
  margin-left: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
}

#subcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25em;
  margin: auto;
}

#patching {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #234090;
  padding: 0.1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22pt;
}

#patchingDesc {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}

#networkMaintenance {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #234090;
  padding: 0.1em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22pt;
}

#networkMaintenanceDesc {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
}

#container #subcontainer {
  animation: slide 13s 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  10% {
    margin-top: -10em;
  }
  20% {
    margin-top: -17em;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    margin-top: -30em;
  }
  41% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  61% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  62% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  63% {
    margin-top: 24em;
  }
  80% {
    margin-top: 17em;
  }
  90% {
    margin-top: 10em;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

#clickMore {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  background-color: #0098cc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 0.1em;
  float: right;
  right: 15%;
  top: 15%;
}

#clickMore>a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
}

#tutorialVideos {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  width: 55%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 44em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 41%;
  line-height: 10em;
  background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/VideoBanner.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

#calendar {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  width: 55%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 43em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 41%;
  line-height: 10em;
  background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/CentralizedCalendar.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

a>#calendar {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: deepskyblue;
}

#selfService {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 21em;
  width: 55%;
  bottom: 62em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 3%;
  float: right;
}

#titleSelfService {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22pt;
}

#howto {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15pt;
  margin-left: 19%;
}

#hpsm {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 15pt;
  margin-left: 11%;
}

#imghowto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/HowTo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

#imghpsm {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  background-image: url("http://itcommunicator/infraops/servicedesk/eoc/SiteAssets/LandingPage/HPSM.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

#hpsm>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#howto>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigcontainer">
  <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="upcomingActivitiesTitle">Upcoming Activities</div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="subcontainer">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="patching">Unix Patching 2.0</div>
        <div id="patchingDesc">
          <b>The Unix Team will have a 5- hour regular maintenance on Sunday, 23 

April 2017 starting 08:00 AM ET. There will be no user disruption during this 

activity</b></div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="networkMaintenance">Network Maintenance</div>
        <div id="networkMaintenanceDesc">
          <b>The Unix Team will have a 5-hour regular maintenance on Sunday, 23 

April 2017 starting 08:00AM ET. There will be no user disruption during this 

activity.</b></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="clickMore">
      <a href="#">Click More</a></div>
  </div>
  <a id="tutorialsa" href="#">
    <div id="tutorialVideos">&#160;</div>
  </a>
  <a id="calendara" href="#">
    <div id="calendar">&#160;</div>
  </a>
  <div id="selfService">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="titleSelfService">Self Service</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="howto">
      <a id="howtoa" href="#">How To 
            <div id="imghowto">&#160;</div></a> </div>
    <div id="hpsm">
      <a id="hpsma" href="#">HPSM 
            <div id="imghpsm">&#160;</div></a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```